# Run any number of functions, each on their own thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, list

What is the most efficient way of performing the same function on a collection of objects, each running in parallel? I know I could just do `new Thread(() => MyFunc(myParam)).Start()` in a loop, but is there a better way? This seems like a very ugly way of doing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [...] is there a better way? This seems like a very ugly way of doing it.

Yes, that is a very ugly and inefficient way of doing it. Each thread will consume a lot of resources but your computer can only execute N threads at the same time where N is the number of CPU cores on your computer. So instead of using a low-level primitive like a thread you can build on top of libraries that optimize the number of threads to fit the number of CPU cores.

In your case where you have a collection of objects I suggest:

- [Parallel LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Parallel.For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx)

LINQ code:

```
var result = source.Select(item => ...).ToList();
```

Parallel LINQ code:

```
var result = source.AsParallel().Select(item => ...).ToList();
```

For each loop:

```
foreach (var item in source)
  Process(item);
```

Parallel for each loop:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
  source,
  item => Process(item);
);
```

For loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i += 1)
  list[i] = Process(list[i]);
```

Parallel for loop:

```
Parallel.For(
  0,
  list.Count,
  i => {
    list[i] = Process(list[i]);
  }
);
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, actually. You see I have a class extending `List<T>` which I'm trying to add a parallel for-each-setting functionality to. IE, for each element in the list, perform the operation (defined by a delegate I have in the class) and set the value to whatever that operation returns. So something like `Parallel.ForEach` would be difficult to implement.

Comment: @RogueBukkitDev: If you want to parallelize your code you can benefit a lot by switching to a functional mindset where data is immutable. Then you can forget all about locking and race conditions (at least in theory). The downside is that you will have to copy data instead of modifying it but on modern multicore CPU's you often get better performance and you avoid multithreading heisenbugs that can take days to fix. So instead of modifying your list have you considered creating a new list? Otherwise you can use `Parallel.For` to loop over the list "in parallel".

Comment: I see, that could work. But then, how do I make my List equal to the modified List, unless I loop through each value, setting it to the new value? Or is the performance change for something like that so miniscule it wouldn't matter?

Comment: @RogueBukkitDev: The "functional" way of "modifying" a list where a new list is created: `var newList = sourceList.AsParallel().Select(item => ...).ToList()`. You can then swap references to `sourceList` with a reference to `newList` if that is required. While debugging you can remove the `AsParallel()` or set the maximum degree of parallelism to 1.

Comment: Thank you for the parallel for example, I think that would work best for my situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.Foreach` or `Parallel.Invoke` starting from .net 4.0.

There is very little reason to use `Thread` directly in your code starting from .Net4.0. You can use TPL which is recommended way of achieving Task parallelism or Data parallelism.

To quote [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) from [his book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030171.do?cmp=af-code-books-video-product_cj_0636920030171_7489747)

> As soon as you type `new Thread()`, it’s over; your project already has
>   legacy code

Comment: Actually i don't like "There is no reason to use `Thread` directly from your code", because there are a couple of reasons to use Threads, for example if you want a strict control over the thread management itself. Useful for example in games or for some server applications.

Comment: @FelixK. what do you mean by *strict control over the thread management itself*. There are very little reasons to create thread yourself manually. For example you need a `STA` thread or you need a thread with different priority etc. These are very rare. I've updated my answer as "There is very little reason..."